# Not able to open the browser in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, selenium, mozilla

I am using selenium framework for testing.
In the beginning I was using Windows machine, in that I have used Mozilla Firefox 39.03 and selenium 2.44.0 . Currently I have changed windows OS  to Ubuntu  , but the same version is not working here. I am not able to open Firefox browser while execution.  Is there any version compatibility  in Ubuntu ?

Please suggest something .

Comment: what exception are u getting?

Comment: org.testng.SkipException: Execution Skipped as no logged in session available
at com.testng.listeners.ExecutionListener.onExecutionStart(ExecutionListener.java:39)
at org.testng.TestNG.runExecutionListeners(TestNG.java:1094)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1041)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:207)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:178) I am getting this @MrunalGosar

Comment: thats not the full stacktrace and also please post the exception in original question itself by editing your post

Answer (score 0):

i dont know the exact apporach to ur query but i suggest u that u should use the latest verion of the seleniumserver.jar.

The latest version of jar is selenium-server-standalone.2.53.0.jar.

Try to launch the browser with Follwing code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying this.